# Using the .where method in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've just started using the .where method, and I'm a little bit confused about how to fully utilize it.

I'd like to do something like:

```
@books = Book.where(:author_id => 1 || 2)
```

clearly I know that doesn't work, but I'm trying to demonstrate that I want some extra logic here. some "or" "and" "does not equal" etc.

Any ideas for where I can research this? I was looking in the rails API but I didnt see anything that was that helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`1 || 2` won't work because that expression is evaluated before the function call (it evaluates to 1, so it should be equivalent to `Book.where(:author_id => 1)`.  I would do:

```
@books = Book.where(:author_id => [1, 2])
```

The generated SQL would be `WHERE author_id IN (1, 2)`.

Comment: Hey Cam, that worked great thanks! Any ideas for how I can use where, or a different method to achieve the "and" or the "does not equal" type logic?

Comment: Hey Elliot, unfortunately, the hash argument to `where` doesn't support 'does not equal' type queries (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html "Only equality, range and subset checking are possible with Hash conditions.").  As far as "and" queries go, just add another key to your hash so: `Book.where(:author_id => [1, 2], :bestseller => true)` would compile to `WHERE author_id IN (1, 2) AND bestseller IS TRUE)`

Comment: how should it be modified for mongoid

Answer (score 4):

Look at MetaWhere, https://github.com/ernie/meta_where - this allows that sort of thing quite neatly :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source (no decent documentation!), you can pass through SQL, which can be parameterized like the sql for :conditions, etc., so you can do something like:

```
@books = Book.where("author_id = 1 OR author_id = 2")
```

Not ideal to drop down to raw SQL, but I can't see a more elegant way to do it using the where method.

[Source and absence of documentation here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where)

Comment: I would do `@books = Book.where("author_id = ? OR author_id = ?", 1, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to look at Arel for more complex things.  It is already built into Rails 3 (AR uses it internally).

```
book = Book.arel_table
# range
Book.where(book[:author_id].gt(0).and(book[:author_id].lt(3))

#or
Book.where(b[:author_id].eq(0).or(t[:author_id].eq(3).order(:first_name))

#joins
book.join(authors).on(book[:author_id].eq(author[:id])).
    where(book[:title].matches 'hokum n stuff')
```

Also group by, aggregation and much more.  The drawback is that the documentation is sparse.
[docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/master/frames)

[tests](https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/test/test_select_manager.rb)